# RoR: Unpinning a post with link to change boolean attribute to false?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, model-view-controller, ruby-on-rails-5

I'm looking to have a link to enable a user undo a pinned tweet.

My view

```
 <% if tweet.pin? %>
        <%= link_to '<i class="fas fa-thumbtack"></i> Unpin'.html_safe, pin_tweet_path(tweet), :method => 
        :put, class: "dropdown-item" %>
    <% else %>
        <%= link_to '<i class="fas fa-thumbtack"></i> Pin to your profile'.html_safe, pin_tweet_path(tweet), 
        :method => :put, class: "dropdown-item" %>
    <% end %>
```

My model (tweet.rb)

```
    belongs_to :user, optional: true

    scope :pin,  -> { where(pin:true) }
     scope :no_pin, -> (id) { where.not(id: id) if id }
    
     after_save :ensure_only_one_pinned_tweet
    
   private
     def ensure_only_one_pinned_tweet
       user.tweets.pin.no_pin(id).update_all(pin: false) if pin?
     end
```

My controller method

```
def pin
    @tweet = Tweet.find(params[:id])
    if @tweet.update(pin: true)
      redirect_to user_path(current_user.id)
    else
      @tweet.update(pin: false)
      redirect_to user_path(current_user.id)
    end
  end
```

My route

```
resources :tweets do
    member do
      put :pin
    end
  end
```

This setup enables each pin to be automatically replaced on the user choosing a different pin thereby only having one pin at the one time. This works fine.

But I want to include the option for the user to undo a pin themselves as well and thus have no pins.

What's the easiest way to do this? ty

**UPDATE**

Update with pin controller

```
resources :tweets do
...
    resources :pins
...
end
```

Routes

```
tweet_pins GET    /tweets/:tweet_id/pins(.:format)                                                         pins#index
                                      POST   /tweets/:tweet_id/pins(.:format)                                                         pins#create
                        new_tweet_pin GET    /tweets/:tweet_id/pins/new(.:format)                                                     pins#new
                       edit_tweet_pin GET    /tweets/:tweet_id/pins/:id/edit(.:format)                                                pins#edit
                            tweet_pin GET    /tweets/:tweet_id/pins/:id(.:format)                                                     pins#show
                                      PATCH  /tweets/:tweet_id/pins/:id(.:format)                                                     pins#update
                                      PUT    /tweets/:tweet_id/pins/:id(.:format)                                                     pins#update
                                      DELETE /tweets/:tweet_id/pins/:id(.:format)                                                     pins#destroy
```

View

```
<% if tweet.pin? %>
  <%= link_to '<i class="fas fa-thumbtack"></i> Unpin'.html_safe, tweet_pin_path(tweet), method: :patch, class: "dropdown-item" %>
<% else %>
  <%= link_to '<i class="fas fa-thumbtack"></i> Pin to your profile'.html_safe, tweet_pin_path(tweet), method: :patch, class: "dropdown-item" %>
<% end %>
```

Error

```
No route matches {:action=>"show", :controller=>"pins", :tweet_id=>#<Tweet id: 18, user_id: 2, content: "Pin test", created_at: "2020-11-23 15:15:03", updated_at: "2020-11-23 15:22:39", retweet_id: nil, pin: nil>}, missing required keys: [:id]
```

Answer (score 1):

One of my all time favorite blog articles is [How DHH organizes his Rails controllers](http://jeromedalbert.com/how-dhh-organizes-his-rails-controllers/). So keeping this in mind, I'm wondering why you have a `pins` action. I think your life would be a lot easier if you would just have a `TweetsController#update` or maybe even `Tweet::PinsController` if you have more functionality. With an update function you can just accept the value for the `pins` attribute instead of setting it to true.

```rb
class PinsController
  def update
    @tweet = Tweet.find(params[:id])
    if @tweet.update(pin: params[:pin])
      flash[:success] = 'Pinned tweet!'
      redirect_to user_path(current_user.id)
    else
      flash[:error] = 'Ups, something went wrong here!'
      redirect_to user_path(current_user.id)
    end
  end
end
```

Then just update your routes and views to use the `update` route and it should be fine. No update to the model code should be necessary.

Comment: hi, ty, what would the routing look like for the new pin controller? I'm using resources :pins in my routing and patch in my view but it keeps trying to go to the show action.

Comment: Please have a look at the Rails routing guide https://guides.rubyonrails.org/routing.html. I'm pretty sure this error can easily fixed with some research how routing actually works ;)